# Add static text to the top bar in GNOME

Tags: gnome, 20.10, wayland

Is it possible to add some text to the taskbar (e.g. just to the left or right of the date display), preferably just by editing a config file without having to install any extensions?

I am looking to do this because I log in using several different user names, don't want to have a different wallpaper/background for each of them, and want to be able to tell at a glance which user I am logged in as without having to start a terminal window. So something like the ability to display an "A" or a "B" next to the date, according to which user I am, would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to avoid extensions and your session is Wayland,

add the below command to startup Applications,

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'var userName = imports.gi.GLib.get_user_name();\                                                                                                                            
Main.panel._centerBox.add_child(new imports.gi.St.Label ({ text: userName, y_align: imports.gi.Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER }))'
```

[image]

Comment: There is a Gnome extension "Date Menu Formatter" that allows you to add free text to the left or right of the date. Just add a couple spaces for padding, and you are good.